# How to do pass parameter overrides with SAM CLI and github actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, github-actions, cicd, aws-sam-cli

```
File with same data already exists at 670fb6f94888157ec5334dfc3609421b.template, skipping upload
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: talktodoc-dev, An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [Environment] must have values
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I don't understand why it's asking for Environment when im already passing it in the command.

```
sam deploy --stack-name ${TESTING_STACK_NAME} \
    --template packaged-testing.yaml \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM \
    --region ${TESTING_REGION} \
    --s3-bucket ${TESTING_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET} \
    --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
    --role-arn ${TESTING_CLOUDFORMATION_EXECUTION_ROLE}
    --parameter-overrides \
      Environment=dev
```

I used the `sam pipeline init --bootstrap` to create my CICD. Everything works manually.

Comment: Trailing slash is missing after `--role-arn` in `sam deploy` command.